# About $\int_0^1 f_n(x)dx$ when $f_n$ is $f:x\mapsto2x(1-x)$ composed $n$ times with itself

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, contest-math

The following question is taken from [here](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxudHVtYXRoY29tcGV0aXRpb25zfGd4OjYzN2NiMDBlOWUyZWI2ZTU) exercise $4:$

> Let $f(x) = 2x(1-x),x\in\mathbb{R}.$ Define 
>   $$f_n = f \circ f \circ ... \circ f (n \text{ times}), f_n(x)=f(f(...f(x)...)).$$
>   (a) Find $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_0^1 f_n(x)dx.$$
>   (b) Compute the integral $$\int_0^1 f_n(x)dx.$$

I use Wolfram Alpha to obtain the answer $\frac{1}{2}$ for (a) and $\frac{2^{n-1}}{1+2^n}$ for (b).

However, I have no idea on how to get close to answer. For (a), I try to evaluate the composition directly. However, I have trouble evaluating when $n=3.$ I think we need to interchange the limit and integral but even after that I have no idea.

Comment: You might need some cheeky dominated convergence theorem to interchange the limit and integral.

Comment: For a start, can you show that, for every $x$ in $(0,1)$, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=\frac12$$ And, even before this start, did you draw the graph of $f$ on $[0,1]$? You should...

Comment: @Did: Yes, I did draw the quadratic graph of $f$ on $[0,1]$ on desmos calculator. However, I do not see how that helps.

Comment: This helps, a minima, to **see** the sequence of iterates $(f_n(x))$. From this graph, what happens to $f_n(x)$ when $n\to\infty$?

Comment: @Did: I know that the iterates $(f_n(x))$ will tend to $\frac{1}{2}$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ if $x\neq0$ and $x\neq 1.$ Actually my problem is I do not know the transformation of function composition.

Comment: Good. And now surely you have an idea to use this, no?

Comment: Not necessary to solve (a). (Why don't you follow what the exercise says?)

Comment: @Did: I do not understand your last sentence. The question asks me to solve part (a) first, followed by (b), right?

Comment: "Actually my problem is I do not know the transformation of function composition" is offtopic to solve (a). Thus, solve (a) first and then we shall see what happens.

Comment: @Did: Actually I obtain the limit $\frac{1}{2}$ using graphing calculator. However, I do not know how to show it rigorously.

Comment: Hmmm... starting from nothing to prove something is always a challenge and often slightly absurd, if I may, and at this point we still do not know **any** knowledge you would have or similar exercise you could solve, but anyway... Let us assume for instance that $x$ is in $(0,\frac12)$. What can you prove about the sequence $(x_n)$ defined by $$x_0=x\qquad x_{n+1}=f(x_n)\quad ?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completing the square:
$$f(x)=2x(1-x) = -2 (x-\tfrac 1 2)^2 +\tfrac 1 2$$
We can see more clearly what $f$ does to $X=x-\tfrac 1 2$ by defining
$$F(X) = f(X+\tfrac 1 2) - \tfrac 1 2$$
so
$$F(X)=-2X^2$$
which gives
$$F^{\circ n}(X) = -2^{2^n-1}X^{2^n}$$
$$f^{\circ n}(x) = -2^{2^n-1}(x-\tfrac 1 2)^{2^n}+\tfrac 1 2$$

I get the integral over $x\in[0,1]$ to be $\tfrac 1 2 - \frac 1 {(2^n+1)2^n}$, so there might be an arithmetic mistake somewhere.

Comment: What is the motivation of $X = x - \frac{1}{2}?$

Comment: @Idonknow: you could see it as changing variables to around the fixed point $x=1/2$, or in terms of algebra it's trying to make the transformed function $F$ as nice as possible by eliminating the constant term.